# Formatting a list of strings to output to YML

Tags: java, yaml, dataformat

Here is a piece of data I am working with:

```
snmp-server view DenyAll iso excluded
snmp-server view iso_view iso included
snmp-server view Cust_View interfaces included
snmp-server view Cust_View ifMIB included
```

I am attemping to get it into a YML format as seen below:

```
snmp-server:
    view:
        Cust_View:
            - "interfaces included"
            - "ifMIB included"
            - "etc etc etc"
        DenyAll: "iso included"
        iso_view: "iso included"
```

I've tried to Iterate through the data set, split each piece of data by a space, and use the first two elements in the list as the "key" in the YML file, and the remaining elements in the list as the values. 
However this doesn't fit any other data set which I might want to format in the same way.

**I am not looking for the code to be written for me. I am looking for ideas on how I'd go about doing this and outputting it into the structure I'd like, I'm perfectly fine writing to a YML etc, the only part I'm struggling on is the formatting of data**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (Prefix tree) for your task. Read each line, separate the words by space, and then insert it into a trie. Then start from the root of the trie and try to print the elements in an pre-order traversal and use tab (or space) for indentation at each level.

It also looks like that you need the data be printed sorted alphabetically. You can achieve this by inserting the nodes in a sorted order the trie.

Comment: Do you know any good Java Trie implementations, I've never heard of it before so I'm not sure what would be classed as a good implementation or not.

Comment: You can look here for more information on Trie implementations: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/52trie/. It's not very difficult to implement one yourself and you also don't need to store values (just keys is enough). There is also this implementation from Apache commons (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/Trie.html), which I haven't tried myself.